# Redis stored data expires without setting expiration time

Tags: php, redis

I've stored data in redis, its working fine. The thing is, I didn't set expiration time while storing data. But, It gets automatically expires after 2/3 days. It repeating the same again even if i re-stored it in redis. As per the documentation it won't expire without setting expiration time.

For review :-

Redis-cli Version : 2.2.12

Data stored in redis(using PHP):

`$redis->hset("users", "1_name", "***********");
$redis->hset("users", "1_place", "**********");
$redis->hset("users", "1_email", "**********");`

Is there any default expiration time in redis so that it will be expire automatically?
Please provide any solution / suggestion for this problem.

Comment: Do you have any persistence option on the Redis you are using ? and if not, what does `uptime_in_days ` say from the INFO command ?

Comment: Hi  Rabee AbdelWahab, Thanks for your reply.
I have executed that INFO command and got uptime_in_days:73
And, I don't have idea about persistence option please update me regarding this.

Comment: In your conf file, usually under `/etc/redis/redis.conf` , check if you have `appendonly ` set , and also if you have `save` set also which i used for snapshotting. http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 0):

May be your Redis configured with `maxmemory` value, so then this amount of data in the redis reached, it evicts old data. To fix this problem ensure redis config has `maxmemory` string commented out

Comment: Hi Tema Bolshakov, Thanks for your answer. The "maxmemory" string was commented by default in redis.conf file. And also given the complete data.

# maxmemory <bytes>